# Forcing the process to be killed AND the OS to recreate the activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to reproduce a bug that a user has reported, and am trying to force the following scenario (taken from the Activities page in Android Developer):

> Then, if the system kills your application process and the user
>   navigates back to your activity, the system recreates the activity and
>   passes the Bundle  to both onCreate() and onRestoreInstanceState().

I've tried on the emulator and on the device, both force closing and attempting to force the OS to kill the process (by loading up and using other apps), but with no success. The indication that the above scenario has occurred is if the activity is passed a non-zero bundle (and is not due to a configuration change).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f5bbb45c9517ab9f)

The answer is essentially:

```
For example, run your app so it has some activities, press 
home, use adb shell's "ps" to find your process and "kill" to kill it, then 
select it again from home.  You process will be restarted, with the top-most 
activity started.  None of the others will be running at this point.
```